# Changing the span text within a button depending if an accordion is open or closed

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

I have an accessible accordion and I need to change the text within the span (inside the button) to change from 'DISCOVER MORE' to 'SHOW LESS' depending on wether the accordion is open or closed.

How do I target the span only in the parent accordion. I had this - $('button span').text('DISCOVER MORE') - but it targets all the accordions at once (there are multiple on the page - hence needing to target the parent button only).

```js
$(function() {
 'use strict';
 $(".contentBlockHeading button").click(function() {
  
  var btn = $(this);
  var toggle = btn.parent();
  var content = btn.parent().next();
  
  if (btn.attr('aria-expanded') === 'false') {
   // open
   $(content).slideDown();
   toggle.addClass('closeAccord');
   btn.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
   content.attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
   $(btn).addClass("contentBtn");
   $('button span').text('SHOW LESS')
   
  } else {
   // close
   $(content).slideUp();
   toggle.removeClass('closeAccord');
   btn.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
   content.attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
   $(btn).removeClass("contentBtn");
   $('button span').text('DISCOVER MORE')
  }
  
 });
});
```

```css
.accordion-text {
 display: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 20px 20px 45px 20px;
 margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

.border-thick {
 border-bottom: 10px solid #fec445;
}

.content-block {
 display: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 20px 20px 45px 20px;
 margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

.contentBlockHeading button {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 20px 0 15px 0;
 color: #000;
 background-color: #fff;
 appearance: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 border: none;
 text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;/
    transition: all .5s;
}

.contentBlockHeading button:hover {
 background-color: #efefef;
 padding: 20px 20px 15px 20px;
}

.contentBtn {
 background-color: #efefef !important;
 padding: 20px 20px 15px 20px !important;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contentBlockHeading h3 span {
 background-image: url(../images/icon_showMore.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left center;
 background-size: 18px 18px;
 text-align: right;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 padding: 5px 0 0 25px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: 'ABCSans-light';
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;/
    transition: all .5s;
}

.contentBlockHeading-2 h3 span {
 background-image: url(../images/icon_showLess.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left center;
 background-size: 18px 18px;
 text-align: right;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 padding: 5px 0 0 25px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: 'ABCSans-light';
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;/
    transition: all .5s;
}

.contentBlockHeading button:hover h3 span {
 right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="headingList">

    <div class="contentBlockHeading">
     <button class="" aria-controls="accord-1d" aria-expanded="false">
      <h3>Quality and distinctiveness <span>DISCOVER MORE</span></h3>
     </button>
    </div>
    <div class="content-block" aria-hidden="true" id="accord-1d">
     Copy...
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try put:

`btn.find('span').text('DISCOVER MORE')`

and

`btn.find('span').text('SHOW LESS')`

in each of your both //open & //close condition.